# Rails 5 app on AWS EC2 Ubuntu server: Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a Ruby On Rails on a Ubuntu server - the server is in the AWS infrastructure.

The app is running there for 4 years and everything was fine until last week, when I started receiving these (and similar) error messages:

```
Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device @ io_write - /home/deployer/apps/myapp-production/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log
```

I had to log in on the server and empty the log files - `>unicorn.stderr.log`. Now, this error occurs every (or every other) day.

This is how the log files in my Rails app look like:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 deployer deployer     4096 Sep 28 06:28 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 deployer deployer     4096 Jun 11  2016 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep  9  2017 newrelic_agent.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 19 16:22 newrelic_agent.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 19 16:23 newrelic_agent.log.2.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 19 16:23 newrelic_agent.log.3.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 19 16:23 newrelic_agent.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 19 16:23 newrelic_agent.log.5.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 19 16:23 newrelic_agent.log.6.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 19 16:23 newrelic_agent.log.7.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Feb 20  2018 procat
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer 12480512 Sep 28 21:12 production.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer 71216391 Sep 28 06:28 production.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer       20 Sep 27 12:22 production.log.2.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer       20 Sep 26 15:27 production.log.3.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:28 production.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:28 production.log.5.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:28 production.log.6.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:28 production.log.7.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer  1391716 Sep 28 21:11 skylight.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer   734536 Sep 28 06:28 skylight.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer       20 Sep 27 12:23 skylight.log.2.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer       20 Sep 26 15:28 skylight.log.3.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:29 skylight.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:29 skylight.log.5.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:29 skylight.log.6.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Sep 26 15:29 skylight.log.7.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 May 20  2018 staging.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        0 Oct  4  2016 unicorn.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer        1 Oct  4  2016 unicorn.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer deployer    20480 Sep 28 21:13 unicorn.stderr.log
```

This is what `df -H` says before emptying the log files:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G   13k  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           395M  373k  395M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       17G   16G     0 100% /
none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            105M     0  105M   0% /run/user
```

And this is after emptying them:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           377M  364K  377M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       16G   15G  437M  98% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

The app is pretty consistent, it's not that the traffic increased 10x recently.

I was also trying to look at the biggest files on the server - `find / -size +100M` - and this is the output:

```
/var/log/nginx/myapp_production.access.log.1
/var/log/nginx/myapp_production.access.log
/var/log/btmp.1
find: `/var/spool/rsyslog': Permission denied
find: `/var/spool/cron/atjobs': Permission denied
find: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs': Permission denied
find: `/var/spool/cron/atspool': Permission denied
find: `/var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/polkit-1': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/monit/events': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/nginx/scgi': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/nginx/body': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/nginx/proxy': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/sudo': Permission denied
find: `/etc/ssl/private': Permission denied
find: `/etc/chatscripts': Permission denied
find: `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority': Permission denied
find: `/etc/ppp/peers': Permission denied
find: `/etc/sudoers.d': Permission denied
find: `/root': Permission denied
find: `/run/user/1003': Permission denied
...
```

I looked at these two files - `/var/log/nginx/myapp_production.access.log.1` and `/var/log/nginx/myapp_production.access.log` and the sizes are `219M` and `248MB`.

The `/var/log/btmp.1` file has `330MB`. Can I delete this one?

If I display the size of the `/var/log/nginx` directory - `du -hs .` - the size is `846MB`. Can I empty log files in this directory without affecting the functionality of the application?

Also, any idea why have I suddenly starting running out of free disk space on the server? How should I "debugging" this situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello,  You can empty out logs files without impacting your app, what you will impact is your ability to track errors/user activity (if you use logs for this purpose, It looks like you have new relic for this). You may want to look into rotating logs (you can set files for rotating here /etc/logrotate.conf).  Here is a good command to find folders that are eating up space across your entire server "sudo du -hax / | grep -E "^[0-9\.]{1,}G" | sort -rn -k1"

Comment: Hi @Jon, thank you for your message. I ended up setting up the Logrotate and emptying the existing log files.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use the `ncdu` tool to find the files in the system that are taking up the most space.

Once you have it installed you just type `ncdu <directory>` at the command line and get a nice interface with directories sorted largest to smallest of the directory you want to investigate.  You can navigate down into each directory and find the files taking up the most space.

If your server has been up for four years, it would be inevitable that the 17G hard drive would eventually get used up by server logs.  You probably have a bunch of nginx logs and application server logs that you could delete.

As Jon suggested, depending on your needs, you could set up rotating logs to prevent the server from filling up.  You could also double the size of your storage space if you want to store all that history.